# Как узнать все доступные параметры ядра linux?

Tags: linux, администрирование, kernel, boot

Есть разные кастомные дистрибутивы, в которых используются свои параметры ядра (строка `append` в синтаксисе `syslinux`). Через какой инструментарий можно вывести весь список доступных? К ванильным `ubuntu`, `fedora`, `suse` тоже относится. Я конечно понимаю, что есть документация, но она не всегда успевает за выходящими версиями или разработчики намеренно не пишут что можно передать.

**UDP**. Меня видимо не так поняли или невнимательно читали вопрос. Приведу пример. Есть менюшка в `pxelinux`, которую я в свою очередь выдернул из `isolinux` и дополнил согласно примерам из интернетов. Выглядит она вот так (копипаст, 100% рабочий вариант):

```
label xubuntu-i386
    menu label ^Xubuntu 16.04 i386 LiveNet/Install [WORK]
    kernel xubuntu/casper/vmlinuz
    initrd xubuntu/casper/initrd.lz
    append boot=casper language=en locale=ru_RU.UTF-8 vga=791 root=/dev/nfs netboot=nfs nfsroot=172.16.11.8:/var/lib/tftpboot/xubuntu/
```

Меня интересует где посмотреть ВСЕ доступные параметры помимо `locale`, `root=/dev/nfs` и остальных. `CONFIG_X86=y` и `CONFIG_INSTRUCTION_DECODER=y` из `/boot/config-3.2.0-115-generic-pae` **не нужны**.

Comment: По всем исходникам ядра поискать строки `__setup(`

Comment: @Mike, а если нет исходников (на самом деле конкретно в моём случае есть) можно ли как-то через debug=superduperverbose или print-all-env-from-kernel=1 узнать?

Comment: cat /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic - это не оно?

Answer (score 1):

командная строка, передаваемая программе *linux* при её загрузке, во время её работы доступна любому запущенному ею процессу в файле `/proc/cmdline` псевдо-файловой системы *proc*.

и разработчики программ, и мэйнтэйнеры дистрибутивов нередко пользуются этой возможностью, добавляя в программы/пакеты код, анализиурющий содержимое этого файла на предмет какой-нибудь подходящей информации.

> Приведу пример: есть проект clonezilla. Там можно передать параметры ocs_prerun01. Где его искать?

вот вы и приводите пример таких разработчиков: они добавили в код программы *clonezilla* проверку, есть ли в файле `/proc/cmdline` слово `ocs_prerun01`, и реализовали два варианта каких-то действий, в зависимости от того, нашлась такая строка или нет. очевидно, что искать код, анализирующий содержимое файла `/proc/cmdline`, в данном случае надо в исходниках программы *clonezilla*.

понятно, что «полного списка» всех подобных строк составить просто невозможно даже теоретически.

ведь вы и сами хоть прямо сейчас можете добавить, например, в свой `~/.bashrc` что-нибудь типа:

```
if grep -q моя-собственная-опция /proc/cmdline; then echo "есть такая опция!"; fi
```

а потом добавить подстроку «моя-собственная-опция» в командную строку программы *linux*. и наслаждаться наличием сообщения «есть такая опция» при каждом запуске программы *bash* в интерактивном режиме.

Comment: Интересно прочитать, но полагаю, в вопросе имелись в виду лишь те, что обрабатываются самим ядром?

Comment: что именно имелось ввиду в вопросе, сказать затрудняюсь, но в процитированном мною комментарии от автора имелось ввиду именно это: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605153/605679?noredirect=1#comment824434_605204

Comment: Ой.. Не читал этот комментарий...

Answer (score 0):

Что бы получить **полный** список всех опций ядра, делаем следующее:

1. Скачиваем исходы интересующей нас версии ядра с
   https://www.kernel.org/
2. Распаковываем полученный архив
3. Заходим в корень распакованных архивов
4. Вводим команду make menuconfig

Любуемся полным списком параметров. Долго любуемся... Очень долго !!! :-(

Исправляю ответ, в соответствии с комментарием. Если речь идёт об опциях загрузки, то тут всё проще:

```
man 7 bootparam
man 7 kernel-command-line
```

Там тоже много, но терпимо :-)

Comment: Речь в вопросе не о параметрах настройки, а о параметрах загрузки ядра

Comment: В `man` очень мало инфы, только то что туда написали, реально параметров гораздо больше

Comment: @Sergey, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Клёво, почти оно. Но тут общие для всех, стандарт. А нужно ещё и то, что воткнули НЕ в апстриме. Приведу пример: есть проект `clonezilla`. Там можно передать параметры `ocs_prerun01`. Где его искать?

Comment: @donRumata в исходниках

Comment: @0andriy, а если они недоступны?

Comment: Они хранятся в специальной секции, можно из бинарника вытащить (только перед этим надо ядро декомпрессировать). Запустите на досуге `objdump -h vmlinux`.

Comment: @0andriy, вот! Походу то, что нужно! Попробую и отпишусь. Если оно - попрошу оформить как ответ.

Comment: ** а если они недоступны?** - https://www.kernel.org/

Comment: @Sergey, не, это как послать человека...

Comment: Не понял - почему? Из-за очень большого объёма загрузки? Лично для меня это абсолютно необходимо, т.к. я занимаюсь разработкой драйверов. Так что мне приходится их регулярно скачивать. Но, по любому, если некая фирма Х допилила ядро в своём дистрибутиве и не положила об этом информацию в файл Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt, то выход только один - брать исходы  и искать макрос __setup(). Насколько я помню, именно он регистрирует функции-обработчики параметров командной строки.  Кроме того, есть параметры загрузчика (Documentation/x86/boot.txt) и параметры загружаемых модулей...

Comment: По разным причинам исходников того конкретного ядра может и не быть под рукой. И да, как разработчик драйверов, вы прекрасно осведомлены, что этот макрос не все случаи покрывает.

Comment: **исходников того конкретного ядра может и не быть** - в таком случае, IMHO, и говорить не о чем...